# How to change layout (without coding) in Android Studio

Tags: android, layout, android-studio

How do I change the layout in android studio without coding? I know that in eclipse ADT I just had to right click on the layout I wanted to change in the Outline and choose the option "change layout". How do I do this in Android Studio. I can not find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

When viewing your main activity.xml file, under the component tree right click the layout, and  under the "Morphing" menu you will be able to change to a different layout. Note: my Android Studio crashes when I do this!

Comment: Was this a feature that has been removed? I do not see this at all?
Component Tree > Select RelativeLayout > Right Click > [No Morphing]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/adding-and-editing-layout-components-using-android-ui-designer.html

Answer (score 2):

"Morphing" menu you will be able to change to a different layout

It can only change it to relative / radio / table / grid

No direct Option for linear , Android Studio 1 (latest) not crashing.